# Eigenspace of Euclidean distance matrix.

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control

What is  the necessary and sufficient condition (if there is any) that $n$ orthonormal vectors $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$ are eigenvectors of a  [Euclidean distance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix). When $n=2$, the orthonormal vectors are easily charcterized, i.e., $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$ and $(1/\sqrt{2}, -1/\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't an answer, but it's too long for a comment.  As you're maybe aware, a real $n \times n$ matrix $M$ is a Euclidean distance matrix if and only if the following conditions hold:

- $M_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i, j$
- $M_{ii} = 0$ for all $i$
- $M$ is symmetric
- $M$ is **conditionally negative definite**, that is,
  $$
  x^t M x \leq 0
  $$
  whenever $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\sum_i x_i = 0$.

This was shown in: I. J. Schoenberg, Metric spaces and positive definite functions, Transactions of the AMS 44 (1938), 522-536.

Comment: +1, Thanks, I know this fact. Do you think if it is possible to characterize the orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^TMP$ is diagonal?

Comment: OK, sorry not to have added anything new.  (Personally I find this fact of Schoenberg's rather surprising, in that the triangle inequality doesn't have to be mentioned.)  I'm afraid I don't have any further thoughts.